# Do water filters expire even if underused?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

[This filter](https://www.aquasanaeurope.com/products/aquasana-powered-water-filter-countertop-pitcher-in-white.html) rates a 3 month lifespan with 1210 liter capacity, but I expect to filter only 300 liters in 3 months. Is it still expired after 3 months - if so, why? What degrades a filter while it's unused?

Comment: What does "expire" mean for you.

Comment: @Karl Unsuitable for consumption (health hazard etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things are aging even if not used, like lithium ion power cells.

There is filter aging independent of the passed water volume. There is eventual growth of chemical and microbial stuff. E.g. chemical sediments on the active surface of antimicrobial silver causes deterioration of antimicrobial effect. Active carbon for organic traces and ionex resin of ion exchange can be affected by this as well.

The life span with 2 criteria is very generally –  not limited to filters nor chemistry – always meant  "whichever one is reached sooner".

In a funny analogy, 1.5 L of bottled water have criteria e.g. ( illustratively ) 2 days after opening, or 1.5 L of provided water, whatever comes first. If you drink just 500 mL, the left 1 L does not have an eternal lifespan either but 2 days are still valid.

Comment: Good answer and I've upvoted. Tough reasonable guess or measurements could be made case by case.

Comment: So filters do have post-opening expirable components - sense enough. A trick would be to use up the entire filter and store results somewhere... in a cubic meter container.